# How to get XML nodes content when names include special Characters?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

Im trying to navigate an XML block similar to this one ($doc) using PHP simplexml_load_string and using xpath on $doc to get only the 'Day' block like this:

```
$myday = $doc->xpath ('//Day');
```

that lets me access all data from the block as an object, meaning

$myday->AdultCount;

returns 1 and

$myday->Id;

returns "6a0"

however I can't access "SpecialDeals" content not using:

```
$myday->SpecialDeals
```

nor using:

```
$myday->SpecialDeals->a:string
```

Whats is the right syntax in this case?

```
<Days>
  <DaysId>687</DaysId>
    <Day>
      <AdultsCount>1</AdultsCount>
      <Availability>Available</Availability>
      <Id>6a0</Id>
      <RoomType>Studio</RoomType>
      <SpecialDeals xmlns:a="http://microsoft.com/2003/Arrays">
        <a:string>Best Day Ever</a:string>
      </SpecialDeals>
    </Day>
  <DaysPrice>247.4</DaysPrice>
</Days>");
```

Comment: You are not aware so far that `a:` denotes an XML Namespace Prefix in XML and that you need to specify the namespace next to the element name in SimpleXML unless it's in the default namespace. This is a common question and has been asked before, let me fetch you an existing answer.

Comment: And keep in mind that there are no *special characters*, that is a misnomer. All characters are equal. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the tags with colons in them (aka namespaces) using the [`children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) method:

```
echo $xml->Day->SpecialDeals->children('a', true)->string[0];
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/57192)

This [SitePoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/simplexml-and-namespaces/) explains namespaces in detail.